# Particle を without a verb

Tags: verbs, particle-を

In the sentence

> それぞれの心の中にあるそれぞれの思い出を胸に日常が始まるのだ。

translated as

> And in each heart there are different memories held inside each chest as we turn back to our daily lives.

Where is the verb for を胸に?

[Sentence from Japanese Online Institute blog](https://www.japonin.com/free-learning-tools/teachers-blog/306-handheld-fireworks.html#comments)